# SQL - Create multiple columns for fill rates based on conditions, with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (

ID varchar(10),
GroupCD varchar(10),
SurrogateKEY1 varchar(10),
SurrogateKEY2 varchar(10)

)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, GroupCD, SurrogateKEY1, SurrogateKEY2)
VALUES 
    ('1', 'UNK', '12345', '89225'),
    ('3', 'ABC', NULL, '44658'),
    ('3', 'DEF', NULL, '99658'),
    ('5', 'ABC', '09184', NULL),
    ('4', 'DEF', NULL, '85598'),
    ('1', 'GHI', '80642', '77890')
```

| ID | GroupCD | SurrogateKEY1 | SurrogateKEY2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UNK | 12345 | 89225 |
| 3 | ABC | NULL | 44658 |
| 3 | DEF | NULL | 99658 |
| 5 | ABC | 09184 | NULL |
| 4 | DEF | NULL | 85598 |
| 1 | GHI | 80642 | 77890 |

I would like to calculate the fill rates for the SurrogateKey columns, grouped by the IDs, which I have code for:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SurrogateKEY1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SurrogateKEY2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY2_fR
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY ID
```

| ID | SurrogateKEY1_fR | SurrogateKEY2_fR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.000 | 100.000 |
| 3 | 0.000 | 100.000 |
| 4 | 0.000 | 100.000 |
| 5 | 100.000 | 0.000 |

I'd like to expand this query so the fill rate calculation will be based on the GroupCD = 'ABC' or every other code.

I would like the output to be:

| ID | SurrogateKEY1_fR_NonABC | SurrogateKEY1_fR_ClassFilterABC | SurrogateKEY2_fR_NonABC | SurrogateKEY2_fR_ClassFilterABC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.000 | 0.000 | 100.000 | 0.000 |
| 3 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 100.000 | 100.000 |
| 4 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 100.000 | 0.000 |
| 5 | 0.000 | 100.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |

Does anybody know how to leverage CASE statements or another avenue in order to produce this output?

Comment: Why does ID have duplicate values. Isn't it unique?

Comment: No, it is not unique.

Comment: The name is confusing. I would change it for something like `type` or `kind`, or `region`; something that implies non-uniqueness.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's what I'm working with.

Comment: What version of ms sql server?

Comment: @MaciejLos - Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: So, you can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) :) Have you tried it?

Comment: @MaciejLos - Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: Yes. If i understand you well, you want to group data by GroupCD on  'ABC' and 'NonABC' values. I'm i right?

Comment: That's correct, yeah.  Then create multiple columns based on that grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Its can be done this way :

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD <> 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_NonABC,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_ClassFilterABC,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD <> 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY2_fR_NonABC,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY2_fR_ClassFilterABC
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY ID
```

The result is a little bit different that you expected :

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/S1okMMkI)

Comment: You are right, I put the wrong results in the expected results table. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Can you tell me why there is a difference in results with these two?
`CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_ClassFilterABC`####################################
`CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS Decimal(8,3)) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_ClassFilterABC`

Comment: They are not the same the `GroupCD = 'ABC'` will make difference, have a look here https://dbfiddle.uk/x3SzWT0F

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
;WITH CTE AS
( 
 SELECT ID,
   GrpKey = CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' THEN GroupCD ELSE 'NonABC' END,
   SurrogateKEY1fr = CASE WHEN SurrogateKEY1 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END,
   SurrogateKEY2fr = CASE WHEN SurrogateKEY2 IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE 1.0 END
 FROM TempTable
),
P1 AS
(
 SELECT ID, [ABC] AS ABCKEY1fr, [NonABC] AS NonABCKEY1fr
 FROM CTE AS DT
 PIVOT(MAX(SurrogateKEY1fr) FOR GrpKey IN([ABC], [NonABC])) AS PVT
),
P2 AS
(
SELECT ID, [ABC] AS ABCKEY2fr, [NonABC] AS NonABCKEY2fr
 FROM CTE AS DT
 PIVOT(MAX(SurrogateKEY2fr) FOR GrpKey IN([ABC], [NonABC])) AS PVT
) 
SELECT P1.ID, COALESCE(P1.ABCKEY1fr, 0.0) * 100.0 AS ABCKEY1fr, 
  COALESCE(P1.NonABCKEY1fr, 0.0) * 100.0 AS NonABCKEY1fr, 
  COALESCE(P2.ABCKEY2fr, 0.0) * 100.0 AS ABCKEY2fr,
  COALESCE(P2.NonABCKEY2fr, 0.0) * 100.0 AS NonABCKEY2fr
FROM P1
INNER JOIN P2
  ON P2.ID = P1.ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mJD2VhRw?hide=4)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to divide the results of 2 aggregate `COUNT()`s.
You can simplify the conditional aggregation with `AVG()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT ID,
       100 * AVG(CASE WHEN GroupCD <> 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_NonABC,    
       100 * AVG(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS SurrogateKEY1_fR_ClassFilterABC, 
       100 * AVG(CASE WHEN GroupCD <> 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS SurrogateKEY2_fR_NonABC,    
       100 * AVG(CASE WHEN GroupCD = 'ABC' AND SurrogateKEY2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS SurrogateKEY2_fR_ClassFilterABC 
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JPOumTPr).